# Hex and Rgb colors don't match in Flutter

Tags: flutter, colors

I have a color pallet that I used in my Swift app but certain colors don't match in flutter either using hex or rgb values? For instance my orange `static let secondTintColorRgb = UIColor(red: 242.0/255, green: 133.0/255, blue: 91.0/255, alpha: 1.0)` in Swift, would  be `Color(0xF2855BFF)` but shows a purple.. or `Color.fromRGBO(242, 133, 91, 1.0)` but shows nothing..

I have other mismatches.. my purple shows as a green ..
Is there something I'm missing to do??

[image]

Comment: not `0xF2855BFF` but `0xFFF2855B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 first chars in a Color(0xFF000000) constructor stand for opacity.
You should just put the "FF" you have at the end of the color to it's beginning.

Ex.: Color(0xF15656**FF**) should be Color(0x**FF**F15656)

[Color Class reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html)

**Color.fromRGBO(242, 133, 91, 1.0)** is fine and is orange in my app.

Comment: I see..FF indeed at the wrong spot, but  RGB still gives me the wrong color...